# Is there a way to move Auto_value annotation generated classes in src/main/<xyz> folder instead of target/generated-sources/annotations?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, annotation-processing

I am currently working on moving my exisiting Gradle project to Maven.
I wanted to specify directory for AnnotationProcessor generated sources. Currently they are being generated in directory 'target/generated-sources/annotations', I wanted them to get generated in my 'src/main/xyz' folder.

I tried couple of ways to specify direcotry, but didn't work.

Here is my pom.xml ::

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>5.8.2</junit.vintage.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
</build>

</project> ```
````

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do not generate into `src/` because that area is under version control and would be changed with each build.... the default is to use `target/generated-sources/annotations` which contains the generated/compiled parts..